# OleDbcommand: How to use 'In' - clause with parameters?

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, oledbcommand

I have an OleDB connection in my web application that is linked to the MS Access DataBase with a couple of search parameters (`OrderID`, `LineNumber`) as the Input. This worked fine in the last years.

Now I was asked to enable the search for multiple `LineNumbers` (e.g.: 2,3,8).
If I hardcode this it works of course:

```
and ([Position] in ('2','3','8') or @LINENUM ='')
```

How can I achieve this dynamically with the given input format as a comma separated string?

I was trying to build a string with the `LineNumbers` outside the OleDBcommand string with C# and then pass the parameter, but it won't work.

```
and ([Position] in @LineNumbers or @LINENUM ='')
```

I also was trying to build a table with the `LineNumbers` inside the OleDBcommand like:

```
DECLARE @LineNumber TABLE (Value INT)
INSERT INTO @LineNumber VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO @LineNumber VALUES (3)
INSERT INTO @LineNumber VALUES (8)

and ([Position] IN (SELECT Value FROM @LineNumber))
```

but then the error

> "Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'"

was thrown.

How can I do this?

---

This is what my code looks like:

```
string SelectOleDb = @"SELECT SalesID, CertificationID, CalibrationDate, Path
                       FROM Zeugnis WHERE (SalesID = @SALESID or @SALESID = '') 
                               and ([Position] = @LINENUM or @LINENUM ='')

                       UNION ALL

                       SELECT SalesID, CertificationID, CalibrationDate, Path
                       FROM Zeugnis_2016 WHERE (SalesID = @SALESID or @SALESID = '') 
                               and ([Position] = @LINENUM or @LINENUM ='')

                       UNION ALL

                       SELECT SalesID, CertificationID, CalibrationDate, Path
                       FROM Zeugnis_2015 WHERE (SalesID = @SALESID or @SALESID = '') 
                               and ([Position] = @LINENUM or @LINENUM ='')
                       ORDER BY CalibrationDate, CertificationID";

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\XXXXXXXX");
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
cmd = new OleDbCommand(SelectOleDb, con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SALESID", SALESID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LINENUM", LINENUM.Text);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change this line:

```
and ([Position] in @LineNumbers or @LINENUM ='')
```

to something like this in C#:

```
string LineNumber = "('2','3','8')"; // build this string dynamically

string sqlCondition = " and ([Position] in " + LineNumbers + " or @LINENUM ='')";
```

then concatenate the `sqlCondition` string to your main `SELECT` string.

If you want the complete example then post your complete code snippet which runs the SQL query via OleDB.

Comment: [Position] is a column in the select string and therefore can't be used statically in the sqlCondition string. Or are you proposing something like building the query dynamically and then execute it? I guess this won't work with OdeDb.

Comment: @Barnabeck yes, I propose you building this `string SelectOleDb` string dynamically and NOT using this param `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LINENUM", LINENUM.Text);` to pass a list of possible values for `IN` clause.

Comment: Now I got it! Thank you. I was confused because I thought your hint was pointing at DynamicSQL.